# How do you debug an android 'aapt failed' error

Tags: android

I get this error and I dont now how to resume it. Does any one have the solution?

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':SGMA:processDebugResources'.
>   Running C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\aapt.exe failed. See output

Comment: I'm confused. What app are you running that generates this error? Eclipse? Where are you seeing the error? Console output? Logcat output? If you're seeing it on the console, check your logcat output for more details, then if that doesn't tell you what's wrong, post the output here for us to look at.

Comment: It is Android studio as evident from the install path of aapt.  aapt is part of the Android build toolchain, so it would not be a logcat message (those are runtime only).

Comment: @Chris Stratton So where can one see the output from aapt, if you work in Android Studio?

Comment: @Edward Falk Run gradle on command line: gradle build This way you will get more output.

Comment: Make sure all files under your "res" folder are lowercase.  This includes the files in your drawables, layout, menu, values.  They must be lowercase.  I hate this error and have gotten stuck on it a few times.

Comment: In my case the problem was that file names in res folder contained upper case letters. Which turned to be not allowed. After renaming all files to low case the problem has gone.

Comment: This is a real question. Got here by looking for an answer to this very exact question.

Comment: @user2517504  Look in your build.gradle file's buildscript section.  You need to have something like this:
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your sdk is out of date, open it manualy and update android sdk's

```
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\SDK Manager.exe
```

and install updates.